# Passing base64 image to PHP page works on localhost but not server

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, base64, localhost

This is my first post, so excuse my lack of knowledge in certain areas.

I am trying to send a base64 image to a php page. It works fine on my testing localhost, but not on the server once I upload it.

I have a canvas element that allows the user to draw, then save the image. Once the image is saved to the div id="result", I then use jquery to paste the div inside the value of a hidden input field, then submit the form to my canvas.php page. Code here:

`<script type="text/javascript">`
`$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#canvasform').submit(function(){

        $('#pass_result').val(

            $('#result').html()

        );

    });

});

<script>`

`<body>`
`<canvas id="thecanvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>`
`<form action="canvas.php" method="post" id="canvasform"/>`
`<input type="hidden" name="pass_result" id="pass_result" /><br />`
`<input type="button" id="save" value="Save Image"><br>`
`<input type="submit" />` 
`</form>`
`<div id="result"></div>`
`</body>`

This works fine when I view the page on my localhost. But once I upload the files and view the page, it does not show the image properly on the canvas.php. When on localhost, I can right click on the image and view in new tab.

The url reads: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...
When on server, I right click and view in new tab. The url reads: http://mydomain.com/%22data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg... and gives me a 414 Request-URI Too Large error.

Any thoughts on why this does not display the image properly?

canvas.php:
`<?php

$thediv = $_POST['pass_result'];

echo "Hello $thediv";

?>`

Comment: Maybe there is some server limit.

Comment: it may have a limit, but even so, the image url when displayed in a new browser window displays http://mydomain.com/%22 before the actual data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg.... The image would show up if it wasnt adding that info before the actual image.

Comment: <form action="canvas.php" method="post" id="canvasform"/>
Didn't you close your form prematurely here?

Answer (score 0):

there is a 8190 (max) characters limit to a url length. If the length of your url + base64data goes beyond that or whatever the your server limit is set to, then you get a 414 status.